# How do I fetch Cake Build prerelease addin from alternative source?

Tags: c#, cakebuild

We're creating an internal use Cake addin for our build scripts.

We're currently publishing it as pre-release to an internal feed, we've previously consumed addins from NuGet with `#addin [id]` syntax like this:

```
#addin "Cake.FileHelpers"
```

Is it possible to change the default feed or specify the feed in any way? And is there a way to indicate that pre-release is allowed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated on the [Preprocessor directives](http://cakebuild.net/docs/fundamentals/preprocessor-directives) page on [cakebuild.net](http://cakebuild.net), the `#addin` directive also supports an URI syntax (`#addin nuget:[uri]?package=packageid[&parameters]` ) which can be used to specify parameters like feed, version & prerelease.

Example usage:

```
#addin nuget:?package=Cake.Foo
#addin nuget:?package=Cake.Foo&version=1.2.3
#addin nuget:?package=Cake.Foo&prerelease
#addin nuget:https://myget.org/f/Cake/?package=Cake.Foo&prerelease
```

You can also override the default nuget location for all addins by specifying the `NUGET_SOURCE` environment variable, the `--nuget_source` argument to Cake or adding a config file like below

```
[Nuget]
Source=http://myfeed/nuget/
```

You save it as `cake.config` and place it along your `build.cake` file.
You can read more about Cake configuration [here](http://cakebuild.net/docs/fundamentals/configuration) and the default values [here](http://cakebuild.net/docs/fundamentals/default-configuration-values)

But to fetch latest prerelease version I would suggest going with `#addin nuget:[feedurl]?package=[packageid]&prerelease` syntax.